# Unable to setup starting form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am not able to set up my particular form in VS.

My project has three forms: 
- Form1, 
- Form2 and 
- Form3.

I want to open **Form3** as start up form but unable to do so.

I **changed** the **startup** from properties but it is not working.

Comment: restart your visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Restart your visual studio

[How to: Choose the Startup Form in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2whfskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and choose Properties.
2. The Project property page opens with the Application properties
   displayed.
3. Choose the form you want as the startup form from the Startup Object
   drop-down list.

Or Else  In code behind

You can change the startup form in ApplicationEvents.vb.

[The ApplicationContext.MainForm property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.mainform.aspx) can be used to set the main form.

```
Public Sub Me_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
  Me.ApplicationContext.MainForm = frmLogin
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From the menu, find Build > Clean "project name"

if it doesn't work, restart visual studio.